# I keep getting syntax errors when I can't find anything wrong

Tags: python, sql

Probably a stupid question, but I'm just trying to make a new table in my database called 'projects'. I can't find any syntax errors, but every time I try to run it it says there is a syntax error on the final line `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "MAX": syntax error`. The table is not created, and it works without the `pjct_pic varbinary(MAX) not null` . The table should be created but every time I run it it just churns out the same error.

```
connie = sqlite3.connect('eeg.db')
c = connie.cursor()



c.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
pjct_name TEXT,
pjct_nick TEXT,
pjct_time TEXT,
pjct_pic varbinary(MAX) not null
)
""")
```

Comment: I'm using SQLite 3

Comment: There is no `varbinary` in SQL LITE database. You can use `blob`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `VARBINARY(MAX)` type is available on SQL Server, but not SQLite.  On SQLite, the closest actual type would be `BLOB`.  There might be an *affinity* in SQLite to which `varbinary` would map, but that affinity would be `BLOB`.  So, I recommend just using this create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    pjct_name TEXT,
    pjct_nick TEXT,
    pjct_time TEXT,
    pjct_pic BLOB NOT NULL
);
```